# Automatic width and height tag for image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a small PHP script, in a page I have a list of images like this :

```
<image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo-1200x630.jpg" >
</image>
```

what i need is to add a width and height attribute for each images so i can get this

```
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo-1200x630.jpg" width="1200" height="630" >
  </image>
```

PS: The width and the height of the image should be automatically calculated based on the link of the picture.
Is it possible to do this using Jquery or javascript ?

Comment: why not getting the image size using PHP? Usign JS you need to perform another async call to that image before setting the attribute to the `image` tag

Comment: you can already do it using PHP script, you can make use of the php  function getimagesize.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: I can't do this using PHP because in this page all the info are submitted using jquery. The user press on add button and put the link then this image tag is generated using Jquery.@RokoC.Buljan

Comment: You should provide the part of the code that generates the XML, nobody can help fix code that isn't there.

Comment: Here is a link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the image in javascript using an `Image` object. Then you can grab the widths and heights.

```
var img = new Image();
$("svg image").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('xlink:href');
    img.src = link;
    $(this).attr('width', img.width);
    $(this).attr('height', img.height);
});
```

See:

https://jsfiddle.net/kfmvhokd/3/

Comment: unfortunately they don't ! the tag i am using is for SVG.

Comment: It doesn't work the width and the height on the link you sent are 2000 which is not exact.

Comment: @BelatarYassine No; I set the SVG canvas size to some arbitrary value for testing. The sizes of the images themselves are set dynamically (as can be seen by the image you provided receiving the correct size).

Comment: So why width and height are not added to the image tag ?

Comment: @BelatarYassine They are. Do you see the image appear in the canvas?