# How to solve the 'cannot read property '0' of undefined' error?

Tags: jquery

I am working on MVC 5 project, there I am trying to crop and validate the image width and height.

Here jQuery code, `reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0])` is occurring error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' .

```js
var imageCropWidth = 0;
    var imageCropHeight = 0;
    var cropPointX = 0;
    var cropPointY = 0;
 
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    $('#files').change(function () {
        debugger
        var file, img;
        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                if (this.width <= 200 && this.height <= 200) {
 
                    var reader = new FileReader();
 
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
 
                        document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
                        var jcrop_api = $('#image').Jcrop({
                            setSelect: [500, 500, 10, 10],
                            allowMove: true,
                            allowResize: false,
                            onChange: setCoordsAndImgSize,
                            boxWidth: 500,
                            boxHeight: 500
                            //onSelect: updatePreview
 
                        });
                        //jcrop_api.setOption({ allowMove: false });
                        //jcrop_api.setOption({ allowResize: false })
                    };
 
                    // read the image file as a data URL.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                    loadPopup();
                }
                else {
 
                    //$("#txtfileTitle").attr("placeholder", "Upload Image");
                    var message = "Image should be maximum 200x200 pixel size.";
                    errormesssage(message);
                    return false;
 
                }
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this error ?

And,
Is this good approach to validate the image width and height before or after cropping?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' is due to the fact that your are attempting to access element '0' of an array 'files' which is `null` or `undefined`. You should first determine why the 'files' you are using is not instantiated when your code is expecting it to be and work from there.

Try using the web developer tools in your web browser to place a break-point on your `if ((file = this.files[0]))` line, and then inspect things to see why `files` is undefined.

Once you get past that, then move on to your crop task.
Your line: `if (this.width <= 200 && this.height <= 200)` may or may not be a valid way to check the image size. Try using jQuery to get a reference to the image object using what's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-the-real-width-and-height-of-an-image-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome).

Good luck!

Comment: the code: if ((file = this.files[0])) is working, but after inside the if condition 'this.files[0]' is become 'undefined' why this is happening ? How can I find 'why files is undefined'.

Comment: this is also working: if (this.width <= 200 && this.height <= 200)

Answer (score 0):

The error with this:

```
this.files[0]
```

you cannot fetch file two times. You have `files[0]` in `file` variable.
use this instead of that.

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - I was trying to get images from an array and got the same message as you did. What fixed it is that I wrapped everything in a ng container that checks whether the information has been received first, something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="conceptCourse.Photos"> <!-- <- this removed the message in the console -->
    <img *ngIf="conceptCourse.Photos[1]['Path']" [src]="conceptCourse.Photos[1]['Path']"
         class="img-fluid z-depth-1"
         alt="{{conceptCourse.Photos[1]['Description']}}">
</ng-container>
```