# Get native/natural width of img and set as max width

Tags: jquery, css

I have a set of images with various widths. I want them 100% width for responsiveness, but no larger that their actual size.

I tried:

```
$("#mainImg").on('load', function() {
var natWidth = $(this).get(0).naturalWidth;
alert(natWidth);
});
```

But nothing alerts.

I also tried this, again with no alert:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImg");
myImage.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert('My width is: ', this.naturalWidth);
});
```

Obviously, I'm missing something!

Once I can grab the width, I assume I can easily use it to set the max-width for the image.

Comment: Where are HTML and CSS of your set? Please add a [mcve].

Comment: You may get some insight here at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-the-real-width-and-height-of-an-image-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this snippet together using your code and it works fine for me. I suspect that your `mainImg` ID doesn't actually refer to an `img` tag, but perhaps an enclosing `div` or some such. Is that possible?

Also, yes, it's easy to set the max width to the `naturalWidth` value. Just use `attr`. I've put an example in the code as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myImg').on('load', function(e) {
        var natWidth = $(this).get(0).naturalWidth;
        alert(natWidth);
        $(this).attr('maxwidth', natWidth);
        alert($(this).attr('maxwidth'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="myImg" src="http://ppls.robertrodes.com/includes/images/Dashboard%20Mockup2.png" />
```

Comment: @webguy I'm curious. Did you find that you weren't referring to an `img` tag, or was something else the problem?

Comment: Stupid mistake I assume. I must have hit the "prevent this page from throwing alerts" so with no alerts, it looked like the code wasn't working.

Comment: @webguy Sounds like something I might do. A prosaic cause if ever there were one. :) Glad you got it sorted out.